# How it is possible that a ket precedes a bra in a matrix expression?

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, notation, trace, matrix-elements

Is it possible to rewrite $\langle a| M|b\rangle$ as $|b\rangle \langle a|M$?

Comment: I beg pardon but why is this physics and not just math?

Comment: Some context for the more casual reader: [bra–ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation). And perhaps *[Duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Duality)*.

Comment: @Greendrake: Related to quantum mechanics? Though it isn't revealed.

Comment: @Greendrake The language employed is Dirac's bra-ket notation, which is used almost exclusively in physics. Translated into math, the question collapses to an evident "no" question.

Comment: The second expression is an [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).

Answer (score 11):

In general, you cannot rewrite $\langle a | M | b \rangle$ as $|b\rangle \langle a| M$. You can see that the two are not the same by just comparing what type of mathematical entity they are: $\langle a | M | b \rangle$ is a matrix element (of the operator $M$), which is a (complex) number. On the other hand, $|b \rangle \langle a|$ is an operator, as is $M$, so the product of the two is another operator, which is represented by a matrix, not just an element of one.

Comment: “$\langle a|M|b\rangle$ is a matrix element (of the matrix $M$)” – no, unless both $a$ and $b$ happen to be basis vectors.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, but one is free to choose whichever basis they like, so there is a matrix representation of the operator $M$ for which $\langle a | M | b \rangle$ is an actual element of that matrix. Apart from that, Dirac's notation is designed to be independent of the choice of basis and at least in the quantum mechanics lectures I heard and the books I read the term "matrix element" was used for any bra-operator-ket-expression. If this is not common practice, I'd appreciate being pointed to literature confirming this and will of course reformulate my answer accordingly.

Comment: Fair enough, but then don't say “of the matrix $M$”. That suggests that you already committed to representing operator-$M$ in a given basis, which will in general not include $a$ or $b$.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I replaced "matrix" with "operator" now where appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

The expressions you write are extensions in infinite-dimensional Hilbert space of plain matrix expressions.

Their analogs for finite dimensional real vector spaces and their matrices  indexed by a finite set of indices *i,j*, whose repeated form implies summation over the whole set, are
$$
|a\rangle ~~\mapsto ~~ a_i \\
|b\rangle ~~\mapsto ~~b_i\\
M~~\mapsto M_{ij}\\
\langle a|M|b\rangle ~~\mapsto a_iM_{ij}b_j , ~~\hbox{ a scalar},\\
|b\rangle \langle a|M   ~~\mapsto ~~  b_j a_i M_{ik}, ~~\hbox { a dyadic matrix,} \leadsto \\
\operatorname{Tr}(|b\rangle \langle a|M ) =\langle a|M|b\rangle  ~~\mapsto ~~ a_i M_{ij} b_j  .  $$

Answer (score 2):

Thinking in component form makes it easier to predict what kind of objects you will be getting out of Dirac notation. The expression $\langle a|M$ gives
a bra (row vector):
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_1^*& a_2^* \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}M_{11} & M_{12}\\ M_{21}&M_{22}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a_1^*M_{11}+a_2^*M_{21} &a_1^*M_{12}+a_2^*M_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$
If we define $\langle c|=\langle a|M$ then your question becomes "is $\langle c|b\rangle$ the same as $|b\rangle\langle c|$?" They are not the same; the first expression is a scalar
$$\langle c|b\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}c_1^*&c_2^*\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{pmatrix}=c_1^*b_1+c_2^*b_2$$
while the second expression is a linear operator (matrix):
$$|b\rangle\langle c|=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_1^*&c_2^*\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b_1c_1^* &b_1c_2^*\\ b_2c_1^*&b_2c_2^*\end{pmatrix}$$
Heuristically you can see that $|b\rangle$ expects a bra on the left while $\langle c|$ expects a ket on the right. So the expression $|b\rangle\langle c|$ expects a bra on the left as well as a ket on the right.